# "No protocol specified , Could not open X display" error when Running bleachbit as root on KDE

Tags: kde, root, gtk, bleachbit

I have this error when running [bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/) through `sudo` or as root:

```
~$ sudo bleachbit
No protocol specified
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
Could not open X display
```

I  have ubuntu 14.04, bleachbit 1.0.

**Update:** tested also bleachbit 1.8, same issue.

Comment: There is no need to run bleachbit as root ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen but it can't delete unneeded files not owned by user

Comment: What files would that be ?

Comment: apt cache for example

Comment: `sudo apt-get clean` IMO you really should not be using bleachbit on system files.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help, it seems others have had this issue as well:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bleachbit/+bug/1377719

Comment: As noted in the bug, BleachBit version 1.6 adds a warning for the option KDE - Temporary Files. The bug ticket also explains when this is an issue.

Comment: Thanks for that, I skimmed the page, and it seemed that there was no clear answer, so I linked it hoping it could be helpful. Thanks @Andrew for clearing it up for me. I've had the error in the past, but figured out how to fix it, though I cannot remember exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

In BleachBit through at least version 1.8 you need to avoid KDE - Temporary Files, or in the preferences maybe you can whitelist a file that looks like `~/.kde/tmp-(username)-desktop14/xauth-1000-_0` assuming its filename does not change.

(Thanks to @dooley_labs for referencing bug 1377719.)

Comment: The tool is crashing at the start as root, I can't get to the preferences.

Comment: bigOTHER: The "tool" is BleachBit? Have you tried logging out or rebooting to reinitilize the KDE xauth file?